# How do I access individual components of json response - Angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a controller that returns a json array with one index in it - a json string containing three different properties - whiteLedvalue - blueLedValue - variousColorLedValue.

In my controller I have something like this:

```
function getLedData()
{
  ledService.getLedData()
  .then(function(response){
    ctrl.ledData = response.data;
  });
}
```

And in my dashboard HTML file I have this:

```
  `<tr ng-repeat="led in ctrl.ledData">
    <td> LED Value</td>
    <td >
        {{ led }}
    </td>
  </tr>`
```

I would like to access just the white values and place them in a td and then the blue in another td etc....

I tried this:

```
`<tr ng-repeat="led in ctrl.ledData.whiteLedValue">
    <td> LED Value</td>
    <td >
        {{ led }}
    </td>
 </tr>`
```

And it did not work.  I assume it has something to do wiht the fact that I am returning an array and I need to access the correct index.  But I cannot seem to figure out if I'm supposed to set the white/blue/various values to their own ctrl.whatever or I should try to access them within the html.  Any help on getting these individual fields would be great.  The only way I can get it to work is by returning the entire json string.

Comment: So, what does `response.data` look like?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP- [{"whiteLedValue":"101","blueLedValue":"220","variousColorLedValue":"140"}]
I think the square brackets indicate its a json array.  What I want to do is access whiteLedValue individually - etc.

Comment: to loop over an object use `<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in ctrl.ledData[0]>{{key}}, {{val}}</div>"`

Comment: Why not just create the different td with {{ctrl.ledData.whiteLedValue}}, etc.  No need to create the ng-repeat.

Comment: @Daniel_L- I did this:
       <div ng-app="reefApp" ng-controller="dashboardController as ctrl">
      <div ng-repeat="(key, val) in ctrl.ledData[0]">
  {{key}}, {{val}}
     </div>
            </div>

And got a blank page.  It did not work.

Comment: @will - I tried that and it returned nothing.

Comment: What about `ctrl.ledData = response.data[0];` and `<td ng-bind="ctrl.ledData.whiteLedValue"></td>`

Comment: @Smokey, this change:
ctrl.ledData = response.data[0];
kills the whole thing and my page returns nothing.

Comment: @VinnyGuitara - Make sure you call $digest or $apply in the callback so the view gets updated with the latest data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you parse the json-string to a javascript array yet?

```
ctrl.ledData = JOSN.parse(response.data);
```

Further reading:
https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: I did this:
    'function getLedData()
   {
      ledService.getLedData()
      .then(function(response){
        ctrl.ledData = JSON.parse(response.data);
          });
      }'

And it broke the page... left me with nothing on the screen.

Comment: What does the console say? shift+crtl+i on firefox or chrome

Comment: Error: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
getLedData/<@http://localhost/ReefController/testTrunk/app/js/index.js:39:24

Is this because response.data is an array of json objects?  This array (for testing purposes) only holds one object at this point.

Comment: if response.data is an array of json strings you can extract the first object through: ctrl.ledData = JOSN.parse(response.data[0]);

Comment: So I changed my php page to remove the json array and provide one json string:

{"whiteLedValue":"101","blueLedValue":"220","variousColorLedValue":"140"} 

Using JSON.parse on that give me a blank page.  Is this not a valid JSON string?

Comment: To translate data from php to javascript using the json-format: serverside: json_string = json_encode($php_array);  clientside: javascript_array = JSON.parse(json_string);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98452/discussion-between-saycrispy-and-vinnyguitara).